# Boost singleton trouble

Tags: c++, boost, singleton

I have some class which uses boost singleton. It calls some function from own c++ library. This library is written in make file as dependence.
Now I have another singleton class and it should call first singleton class. After this code I got linkers error about undefined references for functions which are used in first singleton.

When I remove calling first singleton class from second the errors remove. Maybe there is something wrong?

```
class First : public boost::singleton<First>
{
   void temp() { /* Calling function from own library */ }
};

class Second : public boost:singleton<Second>
{
    const First &someInstance() const { return First::get_const_instance(); }
};
```

End errors:

```
In function `First::temp()':
undefined reference to `Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump()'
undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::renderOneFrame()'
```

Yes, there is calling Ogre's functions from **temp** one.

Comment: Maybe there is. But unless you post some code and the error messages you are getting, we are unlikely to be able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors indicate you're not linking correctly with Ogre.

If they disappear when `Second` isn't referencing `First`, that's because `First` is not being referenced/used anywhere else.

Did you try using `First` in your code to check whether the errors remain?